# prevent cursor moving on text input

Tags: html, internet-explorer, input

I  have a few text inputs that I call a JS function when they are on focus. Basically this function changes the value oh this field.
When I do that, on IE, the cursor is moved to the left end of my input. That does not happen in Firefox. It just stays where I put it on the first place.

```
<input maxlength="5"  type="text" onFocus=\"changeValueOnFocus(this);\">";

function changeValueOnFocus(myInput){
  myInput.value = 1234;
}
```

Is there a way to avoid this?
Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of `onfocus` rather use `onfocusin`, that'll make your code to work.

**EDIT**

I just realized, that there is no `focusin` in Firefox. Hence you need something heavier.

The script:

```
function changeValueOnFocus (e, elm) {
        elm = elm || this;
        elm.value = 1234;
        return;  
}

window.onload = function () {
    if (window.onfocusin === undefined) {
        document.getElementById('someinput').addEventListener('focus', changeValueOnFocus, false);
    }
    return;
}
```

and for `input` you'll need an `id`:

```
<input id="someinput" maxlength="5" onfocusin="changeValueOnFocus(event, this);" type="text" />
```

Now this supposed to be a cross-browser solution.

Answer (score 1):

to move the cursor to the end of the textbox 
modify your function like this :

```
     function changeValueOnFocus(myInput) {
     myInput.value = 1234;

     //use this function to select text but in this case just to move cursor to the end 

         myInput.setSelectionRange(myInput.value.length, myInput.value.length);

 }
```